# How does $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ preserve the volumetric quality of a state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, group-theory, lie-algebra, unitarity

The special unitary group $\mathcal{SU}(n)$ imposes $\det U = 1$ which preserves volume and orientation of $\mathbb{C}^n$. How does this translate to the action on a state? What are the volume and orientation of a state exactly?

For example, the Pauli matrices
$$
\sigma_0 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
;
\sigma_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
;
\sigma_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
;
\sigma_3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
constitute a basis for the Lie algebra $u(2)$ which generates the unitary group $U(2)$ through exponentiation $\exp (-i H t)$ where $H = \sum_{j=0}^{3} s_j \sigma_j$ is the Hamiltonian, with $-i H t \in u(2)$ being a vector of the underlying algebra.

For $su(2)$, the identity $\sigma_0$ is no longer a viable basis vector under the constraint. The evolution of a state $\rho \in B(\mathbb{C^n})$ by some special unitary operator $\exp(-i \tilde{H} t) \in SU(2)$ where $\tilde{H} = \sum_{j=1}^{3} s_j \sigma_j$, how is it different from $\exp (-i H t)$?

Comment: @NDewolf determinant 1.

Comment: Furthermore, to be a bit pedantic, $\mathfrak{u}(2)=\mathfrak{su}(2)$ only generates SU$(2)$ by exponentiation, i.e. it only generates the connected component of the identity element.

Comment: @NDewolf determinant 1 is constraint on the generated group not the algebra, $su(2)$ is lacking $\sigma_0$ for that reason. Exponentiation is the infinitesimal application $(\mathrm{Id} + A/N)^N$ infinite times (where $A$ is any element of the algebra), at the identity which is a group element, but the algebra not necessarily have the identity.

Comment: I just saw the issue, it makes more sense now. But then indeed there is no problem right? You just use the 3 basis vectors. There is no identity for $\mathfrak{u}(2)$, as I remarked in  my other comment these algebras coincide.

Comment: @NDewolf I want to know, how are the generated orbits different, $SU(2)$ is said to preserve volume and orientation, what does that look like for states?

Comment: It preserves the inner product of states.

Comment: @NDewolf Any unitary preserves the inner product, $U\mathrm{Id}U^\dagger = \mathrm{Id}$, special unitary preserves more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121138/discussion-between-ndewolf-and-2ub).